# SQL Agent job history not found for few jobs

Tags: sql-server

I have;backup  ,rebuild Indexes , Update Stats and few other jobs like space alerts, replication jobs 
etc which run frequently on SQL Server 2102-SP2, Build Number:11.0.5058.0

and I do not see any log sucess/Failure for few jobs :

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobhistory 
@job_name = N'Database_Full_Backup_Daily11pm' ;
GO--NO log of Sucess or fail,
```

but the job ran and I see backup files stored on my backup location and I see the database last backup taken date is yesterday 11pm

and there are no other backup jobs are running at all
My backup job uses a custom script not maintenance plans 
Owner of the job are same for all jobs 
all jobs are enabled.
I do not see the history via Right click on job -view history also.
I see agent-properties-history--Limit size 1000, 100 chosen

but for few like below, I see history

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobhistory 
@job_name='Replication agents checkup'
GO----I see history

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobhistory 
@job_name = N'Distribution clean up: distribution' ;
GO----I see history
```

what could be wrong here ? any ideas experts?
Please help

Comment: Check out this blog from Pinal Dave: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/02/27/sql-server-dude-where-is-the-sql-agent-job-history-notes-from-the-field-017/

Comment: Thank you Nepali Rookie but, my job run 1 time every day ..

Comment: Its https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1070/simple-script-to-backup-all-sql-server-databases/

Comment: To me it sounds like, you may have probably reached your max log size limit. How long have you been running this job? You probably may want to setup a maintenance task to cleanup your history log.

Comment: the jobs i created are new but there are replication job running for years, do you want me to clean the history log of sql server?DECLARE  oldest_date DATETIME
SET  oldest_date = DATEADD(DAY,-90,GETDATE())
PRINT @oldest_date
EXEC msdb..sp_purge_jobhistory NULL,NULL,@oldest_date

Comment: Before running that script, I would probably run this query to ensure everything is running properly and your job history log is being recorded as intended. `USE msdb
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysjobhistory;`

Comment: USE msdb SELECT * FROM dbo.sysjobhistory, for this i have all logs other than the jobs i have mentioned above and , i have tested a job to fail and log and now looks like the logs are stored, my backups run tonight, once they run  i will know if my change worked or not..Thank you very much  for the help ...